# Что изначально возвращает While?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
while difference == False:
    difference()
```

Цикл while должен сработать хотя бы один раз, в самом цикле возвращается либо True (чтобы продолжить выполнение кода) либо False (чтобы повторить цикл). Так вот, сработает ли этот цикл хотя бы один раз?

Comment: Вопрос некорректен, потому что `while` — это инструкция (statement), которая в принципе не способна что-либо возвращать. А поведение показанного вами цикла зависит от того, что такое `difference`

Answer (score 1):

Тело цикла не выполнится ни разу:

```
difference = True

while difference == False:
    difference()
```

Тело цикла выполнится бесконечное число раз:

```
class D:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

    def __call__(self):
        pass


difference = D()

while difference == False:
    difference()
```

Тело цикла выполнится заданное число раз. В этом примере десять:

```
class D:
    def __init__(self):
        self._n = 10

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._n != 0

    def __call__(self):
        self._n -= 1


difference = D()

while difference == False:
    difference()
```

Answer (score 0):

Нет, так как при входе в цикл difference это имя функции, то есть объект, а объект по умолчанию всегда исина.

```
def a:
   return False

bool(a)
#True
bool(a())
#False
```

не путайте вызов функции и её имя

Comment: Ваш ответ неверный или по крайней мере неполный, так как основан на допущении. Вот пример кода, когда цикл while сработает и вообще будет вечным https://pastebin.com/aCXCkzsr

Comment: @andreymal `т, а объект по умолчанию всегда исина.`, ключевое отличие названия функции от её результата описано, ваш пример лишь частности, где можно ещё применить контекст по типу функция открывает файл и уже от его наличия... то есть частности.

Answer (score 0):

Это не сработает, т.к. `difference` будет равен по умолчанию `True`,объекты в пайтоне равны истине. Это ответ на основе того, что вы не показали функцию difference, поэтому поведение будет зависеть от функции.

Answer (score 0):

Выполнение функции до `True`

```py
import time

while not difference():
    time.sleep(.01)
```